In what order do spells and attraction visit abilities go on the stack when visiting attractions?
Let's say I have put different spells under different attractions using Myra the Magnificent's activated ability. The different spells are A, B, C under attraction 1, 2, 3. On my first main phase I roll a 6 to visit all attractions. In what order do the attraction abilities go on the stack? And in what order do the spells that trigger when I visit the corresponding attraction go on the stack?

You choose the order of all of the abilities triggered by visiting your attractions, and as a result, you also control the order in which you cast the spells.
Myra's activated ability says the following:

{X}, {T}: Exile target instant or sorcery card with mana value X from your graveyard and choose an Attraction you control that doesn't have a midway counter on it. Put a midway counter on it. For as long as that Attraction is on the battlefield, whenever you visit it, copy the exiled card. You may cast the copy without paying its mana cost.

Once the activated ability resolves, it creates the delayed triggered ability highlighted in bold that triggers whenever you visit that attraction. The steps to visit an attraction are described in rules 704.3g and 701.49a

703.4g. Immediately after the action of placing lore counters has been completed, if the active player controls any Attractions, that player rolls to visit their Attractions. See rule 701.49, "Roll to Visit Your Attractions."
701.49a. To roll to visit your Attractions, roll a six-sided die. Then if you control one or more Attractions with a number lit up that is equal to that result, each of those Attractions has been "visited" and its visit ability triggers. See rule 717, "Attraction Cards," and rule 702.159, "Visit."

So, once you roll to visit your attractions, you simultaneously visit all of the attractions with the number you rolled lit up. This triggers each of those attraction's visit abilities and the delayed triggered ability for each of those attractions with a midway counter. Since you control all of those triggered abilities and you are putting them all on the stack at the same time, you choose the order in which they go on the stack, as described in rule 603.3b:

If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, the abilities are placed on the stack in a two-part process. First, each player, in APNAP order, puts each triggered ability they control with a trigger condition that isn't another ability triggering on the stack in any order they choose. (See rule 101.4.) Second, each player, in APNAP order, puts all remaining triggered abilities they control on the stack in any order they choose. Then the game once again checks for and performs state-based actions until none are performed, then abilities that triggered during this process go on the stack. This process repeats until no new state-based actions are performed and no abilities trigger. Then the appropriate player gets priority.

Then, once all of the abilities are on the stack, you resolve them one at a time from top to bottom. Each time you resolve one of the delayed triggered abilities created by Myra's activated ability, it instructs you to cast a copy of a card, so you cast that spell on top of the stack. Then you resolve that spell before continuing to resolve any other of the triggered abilities.
